# Unique Indexes not working for Sequelize Model

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a unique index for a model that's not working. Here is my model

```
const Script = sequelize.define('Script', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  deletedAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: true
  },
}, {
  indexes: [
    {
      unique: true,
      fields: ['userId', 'name', 'deletedAt']
    }
  ],
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true
});

User.Script = User.hasMany(Script, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false,
    name: 'userId'
  },
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
});

Script.User = Script.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
```

I checked the database and the index exists. So when I create 2 scripts with the same userId and name, it doesn't throw an error as expected. Instead I'm able to create 2 records with the same values for all fields in the index. Both of these records have `deletedAt: null`. Maybe it has something to do with the the field `deletedAt` but I'm not sure why. When I created the index with just `['userId', 'name']` that seemed to work. Any one have any ideas as to why the unique index with `deletedAt` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding that postgres doesn't considered two null values as equal (Thank you Frank Heikens), I can rewrite my index this way so that I can achieve the unique constraint I desire.

```
   indexes: [
    {
      unique: true,
      fields: ['userId', 'name'],
      where: { deletedAt: null }
    }
  ]
```

This way the combination of `userId` and `name` will be unique only among rows where `deletedAt` is null.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS):

> In general, a unique constraint is violated if there is more than one
> row in the table where the values of all of the columns included in
> the constraint are equal. By default, two null values are not
> considered equal in this comparison. That means even in the presence
> of a unique constraint it is possible to store duplicate rows that
> contain a null value in at least one of the constrained columns. This
> behavior can be changed by adding the clause NULLS NOT DISTINCT, like
>
> CREATE TABLE products (
> product_no integer UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT,
> name text,
> price numeric );

So for NULL's you have to tell the database what to consider unique.

No idea how to do that in sequelize.